# how to use multi-keywords search with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

how to use multi-keywords search with php and mysql ?

I have a product table like this

the keywords field is save the keyword id

```
| id | name  | keyword_ids |
|112 | apple | 123,12,421,121|
|113 | phone | 23,14,12,1    |
```

and the keyword table like this

```
|id | name |
|1 | white |
|2 | eat   |
```

I want use a product keywords field find the similar product, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you define "similar" product? Product with at least one same keyword or product with at least two same keyword, or product which has exactly same number of keyword?

Comment: question is not clear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're set on using this data structure, you can use `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * FROM `products` p
LEFT JOIN `keyword` k ON FIND_IN_SET(k.`id`, p.`keyword_ids`)
WHERE k.`name` IN (?,?,?)
```

What I'd recommend doing is actually from a many-to-many relation table linking a product to keywords eg:

```
product_has_keyword

product_id | keyword_id
------------------------
112        | 123
112        | 12
112        | 421
112        | 121
```

That way you can use index for a join (which will be much faster)